# Are there any drawbacks with extensive use of Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

**From a technical point of view, is there any disadvantage from using generics such as in the method `createColumn()` below?**

```
public static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createColumn(final Class<S> sType, 
                                                    final Class<T> tType, 
                                                    final int minWidth, 
                                                    final Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> cellFactory) {
  TableColumn<S, T> tableColumn = new TableColumn<S, T>();

  tableColumn.setMinWidth(minWidth);
  tableColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

  return tableColumn;
}
```

Previously, I've been creating `TableColumn` objects for JavaFX this way:

```
TableColumn<Example, String> colExample = new TableColumn<Example, String>();
colExample.setMinWidth(100);
colExample.setCellFactory(myCellFactory);
...

TableColumn<Other, String> colAnother = new TableColumn<Other, String>();
colAnother.setMinWidth(50);
colAnother.setCellFactory(myOtherFactory);
...
```

Since I have a lot of columns, I wanted to wrap up creation in a factory method and came up with my `createColumn()` method as a single point for object creation:

```
TableUtil.createColumn(Example.class, String.class, 100, myCellFactory);
TableUtil.createColumn(Other.cass, String.class, 50, myOtherFactory);
```

Creation works fine this way, however, I feel a little insecure about all those generics in `createColumn()` (probably since I've not been using generics very often yet). Is it a *smart idea* to do so? Or does this approach have any drawbacks or insecurities?

Comment: Technically, because of type erasure, you need Class<X> parameters for casting to X and maybe instantiation of X objects. Type erasure means no overhead, just the compiler might sometimes add a class cast check for a known actual type value for a generic type. Even that is compensated with the need for manual type checks when not using generics. It is a favor to us all using generics. The software engineering disadvantage: it is implemented as class parameters only (1), with names, by convention a single capital (2), which when passed to other classes becomes a bit muddy. Java 8 showing that.

Comment: Just to make sure, I get you right: I'll need the ``Class`` object, if I want to do ``T obj = tType.newInstance();`` in my method, right? So in my case, I can most probably remove those arguments, but thank you for your additions.

Comment: Yes, even better coding practice is to invoke the classes default constructor: `tType.getConstructor()`. But also `return tType.cast(obj);` sometimes is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: This is how I ended up with my code, after all of your hints and recommendations.

```
public static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createColumn(final int minWidth,
                                                    final Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> cellFactory) {
  TableColumn<S, T> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>();

  tableColumn.setMinWidth(minWidth);
  tableColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

  return tableColumn;
}
```

Column creation:

```
TableColumn<Example, String> colExample = TableUtil.createColumn(100, myCellFactory);
TableColumn<Other, String> colOther = TableUtil.createColumn(50, myOtherFactory);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics are here only to help us - as you know, it's a compile-time feature that applies checks on the types we're using and prevents from unexpected `ClassCastException`s.

As fas as I can see, you don't use the `Class` object that you pass, so I would rewrite your method to:

```
public static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createColumn(final int minWidth, 
                                                    final Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, 
                                                    TableCell<S, T>> cellFactory) {
  TableColumn<S, T> tableColumn = new TableColumn<S, T>();

  tableColumn.setMinWidth(minWidth);
  tableColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

  return tableColumn;
}
```

and will invoke it like:

```
TableUtil.<Example, String>createColumn(100, myCellFactory);
```

There's no need to burden the method signature with redundant `Class` parameters, since you can just point out the generic types.

Comment: In Java 8 the compiler will be able to infer the types from a (properly typed) cell factory instance, so you should be able to just do `TableUtil.createColumn(100, myCellFactory)`.

Comment: Woah, you are right! I didn't even notice, I'm not using the ``Class`` objects. In some rare cases, however, I set cellFactory to ``null`` and add it later. How is Java supposed to know which types to use for ``S`` and ``T``, if I leave out my ``sType`` and ``tType`` property and set ``cellFactory`` to ``null``?

Comment: If you assign it to something, which you almost certainly do since your method has no side effects, the compiler can still infer the types from the type of the variable to which you assign it. E.g. if you do `TableColumn<Person, String> col = createColumn(100, null);` the compiler infers that `S` is `Person` and `T` is `String` from the assignment.

Comment: Sure, that makes perfect sense. Thank you for pointing it out. Furthermore, with Java 7+ it is possible to use the diamond operator within my method, so I could shorten down the ``TableColumn`` initialisation to ``TableColumn<S, T> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>();`` and Java will infer the correct type here, as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a smart idea to do so? Or does this approach have any drawbacks or insecurities?

Your code is ok. Generics has no runtime cost and exists only in compile time.